# Should I leave the script tag empty if I use an external script file?

Tags: javascript

I mean, if I use JavaScript in an external file(write script code in another file, not in HTML file).

I write this code in my HTML file `<script src="filename.js"></script>`
**But this code works only if I left the tags empty**.

So I'm wondering that if we use JavaScript in an external way, should I leave the tag empty as I **mentioned**?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: I mean, can I add some code between script tags that has src attribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
It's important to note that a `script` element using the `src` attribute should not include additional Javascript code between the `<script>` and `</script>` tags. If both are provided, the script file is downloaded and executed while the inline code is ignored.

[Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1)

Note that html5 allows comments inside an external script tag.
[Reference html5](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-script-element.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements)

Comment: Thanks, it's really healful. :)

Comment: @KoreaStudent Of nothing.  In the past I have also had problems with this, because I didn't know it